# Dropdown list no repeat data values

Tags: c#, asp.net

How would I stop the repeating of data in my DropDownLists?  I couldn't find any good examples of DropDownlists with non repeating values from sql? I tried to make the select statement say Distinct.

Here is my code I am using:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = (string)Session["name"];

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        DropDownList2.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        DropDownList3.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        DropDownList4.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
        String strQuery = "select distinct * from dbo.Vehiclemain WHERE ISENABLED = 'YES'";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            DropDownList1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Year";
            DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
            con.Open();
            DropDownList2.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Make";
            DropDownList2.DataValueField = "ID";
            DropDownList2.DataBind();
            con.Close();
            con.Open();
            DropDownList3.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DropDownList3.DataTextField = "Model";
            DropDownList3.DataValueField = "ID";
            DropDownList3.DataBind();
            con.Close();
            con.Open();
            DropDownList4.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DropDownList4.DataTextField = "Submodel";
            DropDownList4.DataValueField = "ID";
            DropDownList4.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What repeating data? Show us what the results of your query is, and what you expect it to be.

Comment: from SQL sorry repeating values

Comment: You're currently doing `distinct * ..` which mean distinct of all column values which will end up returning all values. Rather do `distinct [column name]` to select the distinct values for the respective column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to change the drop downs based on the first drop down. 
If that's the case, you would want to make the drop down an autopost back as well.
Everytime someone changes the year, a make will be filled based on the year.
Everytime someone changes the make, a model will be filled based on the make .
Everytime someone changes the model , a submodel will be filled based on the model .
The sQL query will be scaffolded as we build the information...

The code below has not been tested.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYearObj" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlObj_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMakeObj" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMakeObj_SelectedIndexChanged" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlModelObj" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlModelObj_SelectedIndexChanged" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubmodelObj" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:DropDownList>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = (string)Session["name"];

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
        String strQuery = "select distinct Year from dbo.Vehiclemain WHERE ISENABLED = 'YES'";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            ddlYearObj.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddlYearObj.DataTextField = "Year";
            ddlYearObj.DataValueField = "Year";
            ddlYearObj.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }

        //Visible!? -- All invisible until something is chosen
        ddlMakeObj.Visible = false;
        ddlModelObj.Visible = false;
        ddlSubmodelObj.Visible = false;
    }
    protected void ddlYearObj_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
        String strQuery = "select distinct Make from dbo.Vehiclemain WHERE ISENABLED = 'YES' AND YEAR = "+ ddlYearObj.Value;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            ddlMakeObj.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddlMakeObj.DataTextField = "Make";
            ddlMakeObj.DataValueField = "Make";
            ddlMakeObj.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }

        //Visible!
        ddlMakeObj.Visible = true;
        ddlModelObj.Visible = false;
        ddlSubmodelObj.Visible = false;
    }
    protected void ddlMakeObj_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
        String strQuery = "select distinct modelfrom dbo.Vehiclemain WHERE ISENABLED = 'YES' AND YEAR = "+ ddlYearObj.Value;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            ddlModelObj.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddlModelObj.DataTextField = "Model";
            ddlModelObj.DataValueField = "Model";
            ddlModelObj.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }

        //Visible!
        ddlMakeObj.Visible = true;
        ddlModelObj.Visible = true;
        ddlSubmodelObj.Visible = false;
    }
    protected void ddlModelObj_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager
            .ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
        String strQuery = "select distinct Submodelfrom dbo.Vehiclemain WHERE ISENABLED = 'YES' AND YEAR = "+ ddlYearObj.Value + " AND Model = '" + ddlModelObj.Value + "'";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            ddlSubmodelObj.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            ddlSubmodelObj.DataTextField = "Submodel";
            ddlSubmodelObj.DataValueField = "ID";
            ddlSubmodelObj.DataBind();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }

        //Visible!
        ddlMakeObj.Visible = true;
        ddlModelObj.Visible = false;
        ddlSubmodelObj.Visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using single query to populate all your dropdowns. Try creating 4 select statments with applying distinct to appropriate column. for ex Make dropdown would have distinct Make in the query.